# AlertDialog: After showing the dialog, background Canvas rendering continues, but the dialog never close

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-canvas, looper

Here's a screenshot of my AlertDialog's unresponsive state:

[image: A screenshot from DDMS that shows the dialog unresponsive, but the rendering thread continues to run.]

In the background, the green tile, the red ball inside a the black-and-white target, all three of the bitmaps are continuously rendered on a rendering thread that locks/unlocks the background Canvas on my phone. This unresponsive action always execute when I press the OK button, regardless of what text I put into the EditText.

Here's the code:

**PlayActivity class:**

```
package nttu.edu.activities;

import nttu.edu.graphics.RenderView;
import nttu.edu.handler.Accelero;
import nttu.edu.handler.TouchHandler;
import nttu.edu.score.Score;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class PlayActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    public RenderView renderView = null;
    public Accelero accelerometer = null;
    public AssetManager assetManager = null;
    public TouchHandler touchHandler = null;
    public Score leaderboard = null;
    final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x1;

    private EditText input = null;
    private AlertDialog.Builder dialog = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        accelerometer = new Accelero();
        touchHandler = new TouchHandler();
        leaderboard = new Score(this);
        renderView = new RenderView(this, accelerometer, touchHandler);
        renderView.setOnTouchListener(touchHandler);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        input = new EditText(this);
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter High Score!");
        dialog.setMessage("Enter your name: ");
        dialog.setView(input);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", PlayActivity.this);
        setContentView(renderView);
    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(renderView != null)
            renderView.resume();
        if(accelerometer != null)
            accelerometer.resume(this);
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if(renderView != null)
            renderView.pause();
        if(accelerometer != null)
            accelerometer.pause();
    }

    public void addPlayer()
    {
        // FIXME: The dialog won't exit.

        Looper.prepare();
        dialog.show();
        Looper.loop();
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
    {
        String name = input.getText().toString();
        if(name == null)
            name = "Player";
        this.leaderboard.open();
        this.leaderboard.createEntry(name, this.renderView.getScore());
        this.leaderboard.close();
        if (Looper.myLooper() != null)
            Looper.myLooper().quit();
        else if (Looper.getMainLooper() != null)
            Looper.getMainLooper().quit();
        Log.d("PlayActivity.onClick()", "I'm escaping from Looper.loop()"); 
        //renderView.running = false;
        //PlayActivity.this.finish();

    }
}
```

For some unknown reason, the AlertDialog will execute only when there's a prepared Looper existing before AlertDialog.show() is called.

**The problem is when after AlertDialog.show() is called upon, and after Looper.quit() is called, AlertDialog somehow doesn't exit, which makes the phone unresponsive.**

And when I called on PlayActivity.this.finish() in onClick() method, I can exit the dialog, stop the background rendering, and go back to Main Menu (which is what I wanted), but Eclipse DDMS reports this:

```
06-26 16:40:29.049: E/WindowManager(1642):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
06-26 16:40:29.049: E/WindowManager(1642):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
06-26 16:40:29.049: E/WindowManager(1642):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:433)
06-26 16:40:29.049: E/WindowManager(1642):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
06-26 16:40:29.049: E/WindowManager(1642):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
06-26 16:40:29.049: E/WindowManager(1642):  at nttu.edu.activities.PlayActivity.addPlayer(PlayActivity.java:77)
06-26 16:40:29.049: E/WindowManager(1642):  at nttu.edu.graphics.RenderView.tick(RenderView.java:119)
06-26 16:40:29.049: E/WindowManager(1642):  at nttu.edu.graphics.RenderView.run(RenderView.java:69)
06-26 16:40:29.049: E/WindowManager(1642):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
06-26 16:40:29.079: W/MessageQueue(1642): Handler{405399b8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-26 16:40:29.079: W/MessageQueue(1642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{405399b8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-26 16:40:29.079: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
```

In short, AlertDialog leaks when I want to quit my PlayActivity by calling on finish(). I don't know what else to do to fix this problem.

Please help me. Thanks! If you need more source code, please let me know.

EDIT:

Just before the Leak errors appear, this is what DDMS logged:

```
06-26 16:40:22.182: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Tee.
06-26 16:40:22.182: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Hole.
06-26 16:40:22.182: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Ball.
06-26 16:40:22.192: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing background.
06-26 16:40:22.202: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Tee.
06-26 16:40:22.202: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Hole.
06-26 16:40:22.202: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Ball.
06-26 16:40:22.212: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing background.
06-26 16:40:22.212: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Tee.
06-26 16:40:22.222: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Hole.
06-26 16:40:22.222: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Ball.
06-26 16:40:22.222: D/FrameRate(1642): 59
06-26 16:40:22.232: D/Level.tick()(1642): Obtaining score.
06-26 16:40:22.232: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing background.
06-26 16:40:22.232: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Tee.
06-26 16:40:22.242: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Hole.
06-26 16:40:22.242: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Ball.
06-26 16:40:22.242: D/Level.render()(1642): Outputting the phrase: Game Over
06-26 16:40:23.713: D/Database(1642): dbopen(): path = /data/data/nttu.edu/databases/Scoreboard, flag = 6, file size = 5120
06-26 16:40:23.713: D/Database(1642): dbopen(): path = /data/data/nttu.edu/databases/Scoreboard, mode: wal, disk free size: 1014 M, handle: 0x38b4a8
06-26 16:40:23.844: D/Database(1642): dbclose(): path = /data/data/nttu.edu/databases/Scoreboard, handle = 0x38b4a8
06-26 16:40:28.608: D/PlayActivity.onClick()(1642): I'm escaping from Looper.loop()
06-26 16:40:28.618: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing background.
06-26 16:40:28.628: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Tee.
06-26 16:40:28.628: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Hole.
06-26 16:40:28.628: D/Level.render()(1642): Drawing Ball.
06-26 16:40:28.628: D/Level.render()(1642): Outputting the phrase: Game Over
06-26 16:40:28.648: D/FrameRate(1642): 2
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642): Handler{4053dbd0} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{4053dbd0} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:457)
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:430)
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:367)
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.dispatchMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:240)
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:151)
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at com.android.internal.view.IInputContext$Stub.onTransact(IInputContext.java:137)
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
06-26 16:40:28.798: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-26 16:40:28.888: W/MessageQueue(1642): Handler{405399b8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-26 16:40:28.888: W/MessageQueue(1642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{405399b8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-26 16:40:28.888: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
06-26 16:40:28.888: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:457)
06-26 16:40:28.888: W/MessageQueue(1642):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:430)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should detect all the places where the app will end up in and use `Dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: I just did what you asked. After stepping over each line, it ends at onClick(). Afterwards, the thread itself quits on its own. All that's left is the dialog itself.

Comment: yes, it's a meter on how many questions you asked got an accepted answer. if your dialog was not dismissed you are missing something. try initiating a countdown timer that will dismiss the dialog

Comment: Working on this little bit, I think dialog.dismiss() AND builder.create() are the keys for a working dialog.